# Exiting Virt-top shows error message in server logs

Tags: centos7, kvm-virtualization, vps, log-files, libvirt

I see message in /var/log/messages after quitting virt-top command :

> libvirtd: 2020-07-11 12:36:22.206+0000: 3462: error
> :virNetSocketReadWire:1806 : End of file while reading data:
> Input/output error

Is it a thing to worry ?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't worry much about this. It only means that the connection between virt-top and libvirtd wasn't closed cleanly. It does, however, indicate a possible bug in virt-top and you may wish to report it to its maintainers.